# Given inputs and output points from a linear transformation, how can we know when there are infinite linear mappings that satisfy the conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Assume we have a transformation $T$ such that $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto  \mathbb{R}^3$ where

$$T\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
-1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix},T\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
2\\
3
\end{pmatrix},T\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
5\\
0\\
-3
\end{pmatrix}.$$

We are supposed to find out if there is any linear mapping fulfilling the given conditions.

You can normally solve these problems by doing $A = Y X^{-1}$, where $A$ is the desired linear transformation matrix, $Y$ is a matrix where the columns are the output vectors we have been provided, and $X$ is  a matrix where the columns are the input vectors we have been provided (in the same order as in $Y$).

In this case, $X$ cannot be inverted. The solution of the exercise says that there are infinite linear mappings that satisfy the solution.

I don't know why. Is this related to the fact that $X$ cannot be inverted?

Comment: In short: yes. Note that $x_1=\frac12 x_2+\frac12 x_3$ and $y_1=\frac12 y_2+\frac12 y_3$ (see [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%2C0%7D%7D%3Da*%7B%7B1%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C2%2C3%7D%7D%2Bb*%7B%7B1%2C0%2C-3%7D%2C%7B5%2C0%2C-3%7D%7D)), thus you have only $2$ equalities, the third is implied from them. What do you do in the case of $2$ equalities?

Comment: Thanks. 1) Is there any reason you put the vectors transposed/'sideways'? 2) I can see why the relation between the xs and ys may result in infinite answers, but I don't understand how is it related to the fact that you can't invert $X$?

Comment: No, not a reason, only that I'm lazy. You can't invert a matrix if and only if it has linear dependent columns or rows, it's the exact cases when the determinant is $0$.

Comment: Thanks, that is now clear. But I still don't truly understand why the xs being dependent and the ys being dependent result in infinite answers. Does the dependency between the xs and the dependency between the ys imply a linear dependency between the xs and ys?